# Alembic not autogenerating tables from SQLAlchemy classes

Tags: sqlalchemy, migration, alembic

sqlalchemy:  2.0.25
alembic: 1.13.1
python: 3.11

`alembic revision --autogenerate -m "initial migration"`
creates empty `upgrade` and `downgrade` code in the migration.

As shown below I have two model classes in separate files from the Base class.

My alembic/env.py is follows their docs instructions to import my Base class so that it can access metadata.  On an empty db, this should produce upgrade code to create the Order and Item tables but it seems like it's not finding those classes from the Base.metadata.  1. On a hunch I put imports of those classes into the env.py  (as shown below) and then the migration is autogenerated correctly.  2. As an alternate workaround I also found that putting all my models into one big file along with Base resulted in complete generation.

Workaround 1 is ok but kind of a hassle as the number of model classes grows.  Workaround 2 is unacceptable.

Is there a more elegant and reliable way to get it find all model classes for autogeneration?

```
#models.base.py

from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

#models.order.py

from models.base import Base

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Order"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    description: Mapped[Optional[str]]
    items: Mapped[List["Item"]] = relationship(back_populates="order")
 
#models.item.py

from models.base import Base

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Item"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255))

    order_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("Order.id"))
    order: Mapped["Order"] = relationship(back_populates="items")
 
 

#alembic/env.py  (excerpt)
from models.base import Base
from models.order import Order # not prescribed by doc but makes it work
from models.item import Item # same as above
target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your Base class in an individual file e.g. `base_class.py`, reuse it in your models definition, e.g. `order.py` and import all your models into a `base.py` file to use in alembic `env.py`.

E.g.

```py
# db.base_class.py

from typing import Any
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative, declared_attr

@as_declarative()
class Base:
    id: Any
    __name__: str
    
    # Generate __tablename__ automatically
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__.lower()
```

```py
# models.order.py

from db.base_class import Base

class Order(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    description: Mapped[Optional[str]]
    items: Mapped[List["Item"]] = relationship(back_populates="order")
```

```py
# models.base.py

from db.base_class import Base # noqa
from models.order import Order # noqa
from models.item import Item   # noqa
```

If you have errors when creating the migration scripts, you can import the models in `__init__.py` of models

```py
# models.__init__.py

from .order import Order # noqa
from .item import Item   # noqa
```

With this, you will not have to update alembic.env.py every time you create a model, but you will have to import it in `models.base.py`, as well as Order and Item.

```py
# alembic.env.py

import sys
from alembic import context
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config, pool
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.append(str(Path.cwd()))
from db.base import Base


config = context.config
target_metadata = Base.metadata

...
```

Comment: I mistakenly imported Base from base_class and got trash migration.  Its important to import it from base as in your code.   No need for `__init__` in my situation.  Thanks very much.